# Connect to port using php_serial_class every minute

Tags: php, sms, modem

If I have a script which will send sms every minute using crontab :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE Status = '0' LIMIT 0,6";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

$serial = new Sms_Serial;
$serial->deviceSet("/dev/ttyUSB0");
$serial->confBaudRate(115200);
$serial->confParity('none');
$serial->confCharacterLength(8);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
         {
         $serial->deviceOpen();

         //sending....

         $serial->deviceClose();
         }
```

Which means it will detect the port and set BaudRate to send few sms every minute.Will it bring any damage to the port or modem?Some of my ports will not able to detect SIM card anymore after some days,I'm not sure whether is the modem quality problem or my script problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried checking to see what happens if it doesn't send the message? Mainly I see that the modem does not support so many traffic/connection and then there might be a bug in your code where if the message is not sent will try to send it again and so on and on instead of reporting it and "pause" the process until you see what is happening, that causes a lot of traffic and if your modem doesn't take it, it will get fried eventually .

Comment: Thanks for your reply.If the message is not sent then it will be ignored and try to send the next message.Will this be the main problem?

Comment: The message might be ignored and tries to send the next message but what really happens with it, it gets dropped or will it try to send it later? I once had a problem with a mail gateway server I was implementing that because of the content and some other factors the hole service that was analyzing and then passing it over to postfix to finally send it to the end user, was collapsing and the message was still in the queue without dropping it from the queue.

Comment: My script will try to send it again in the next minute...So in your case is if keep sending a message which content has problem will bring traffic to the modem? usually my message content is okay since will be checked before send,but just sometimes my port will not able to detect the SIM,and recover after some time,or after I restart the modem for several times(even I didn't use it at all ) or no longer workable.

Comment: well definitely high traffic on a modem will affect if its not designed to take it and on high traffic it means high temperature eventually. You should also check your logs and see what happens when: you check, send, ignore, re queue the message to find if you have any bugs in your code that might make collapse the device.

Comment: According to the modem description,it is design for high traffic communication.Just wonder is it because I connect to the port too frequently?However I will check my code as well,thank you so much.

Comment: What system are you running on the modem? You should check some kernel logs and its drivers, check also to see what else is connecting to that modem and why. Try a different port

Comment: So sorry for my late response.I'm using Ubuntu.Yes I will check and try it.Really thanks for all your advices.